# Assigning a type to shallow clone

Tags: angular, typescript

Is it possible to assign a type (one of two in this case).

```
 static shallowClone(obj: IComponentData | ITemplate): IComponentData | ITemplate {
    return JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(obj)) as IComponentData | ITemplate;
  }
```

In the other document:

```
 activeTemplate = new BehaviorSubject<ITemplate>(null);
 this.builderComponentsService.activeTemplate.next(UtilService.shallowClone(styleTemplate));
```

I get the following error whenever I perform the following operation:

```
TS2345: Argument of type '{}' is not assignable to parameter of type 'IComponentData | ITemplate'.
```

Comment: no need of writing with json.parse. you already have defined return type at method level.

Comment: this doesnt work, i get the error: `Conversion of type 'string' to type 'IComponentData | ITemplate' may be a mistake because neither type sufficiently overlaps with the other. If this was intentional, convert the expression to 'unknown' first.`

Comment: check code below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
static shallowClone(obj): IComponentData | ITemplate {
   return JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(obj));
}
```

or

```
shallowClone= <T>(original: T): T => {
  return JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(original));
};
```

or

```
static shallowClone<IComponentData | ITemplate>(obj: IComponentData | ITemplate): IComponentData | ITemplate{
      return JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(original));
    };
```

or the best one will be, because it works for all types :-

```
static shallowClone<T>(obj: T): T{
          return JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(original));
        };
```

Comment: Thanks, just one quick question. What type should `obj` be? I would like to strongly type it.

Comment: `static shallowClone(obj: unknown): IComponentData | ITemplate` works but `static shallowClone(obj: IComponentData | ITemplate): IComponentData | ITemplate` doesn't work.